# Hibernate doesn't work and hibernate.sys is not in C:

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

My computer is unable to hibernate. When I start the computer and press any key, I'm instantly at the login screen.

I tried running `powercfg -h on` with no possitive effect.

The file `hibernate.sys` is not in my `C:` directory, and I can't restore it.

What could I do?

Comment: How is this a programming related question?

Comment: sorry, dont know that this is only for programming

Comment: There is http://superuser.com where you might get better answers.

Comment: Did hibernation previously work on this system?  Is it actually showing enabled in the Power Options dialog?  How much RAM is in your system - if 4 GB or greater, hibernation will not enable.

Comment: @Iszi: "if 4 GB or greater, hibernation will not enable" - that has not been true since about Windows XP SP2.  And before that there was a hotfix for Windows XP to fix hibernate for systems over 2 GB (and to fix the problems with hibernate and fragmented RAM).

Answer (score 0):

Have your enabled hibernation in Power Options (available in the Control Panel)?

In Windows XP that looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to first disable the hibernation
Then in the windows explorer window
Go to *Tools>Folder Options > View>*
Select 'show hidden folders' and uncheck 'hide system protected operating system files'
Now go to your c drive you should be able to see you hyberfil.sys and delete it too
Re-enable hibernation after these steps it should work.
(This problem usually occurs due to corrupted hyberfil.sys)